# How would I increase the size of my arrow without increasing the size of an image that's in same div?

Tags: html, css, debugging, sass

This arrow that I'm going to be referring to's nested inside a wrapper `div` that contains an image.  I'd post the entire code but the code base I'm dealing with's enormous.

Right now, the only way to increase the size of the right arrow is by increasing the `padding` inside the `.arrow` class. However, when I do that - the image that's nested inside the aforementioned wrapper `div` also increases in size.

I've tried:

- Increasing the size of the arrow using `width` and `height` but getting the same result as mentioned.
- I've tried setting the wrapper `div` to `position: static;` but to no avail.

It looks like `padding`'s the the only way to increase the size proportionally.

My question is - How can I increase the size of the arrow without tampering with anything else inside the div?  Is there a silver bullet way that I can do this?  I feel like there has to be a way to increase the size of the arrow without the use of `padding` that also doesn't tamper with anything else inside of a div.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0v52mb43/12/) for reference.

Here's my html:

```
<i class="arrow right"></i>
```

Here's my css:

```
.arrow {
   border: solid #71AD44;
   border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 8px;
   margin-right: 2rem;
   float: right;
  z-index: -1;
}

.right {
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Comment: please add this code to a code snippet tool inside SO so we can take a closer look at it (minimum reproducible example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `font-size` on class `.right-arrow` to manage the size of your arrow.